# Как с помощью PHP трансформировать Json данные в маркированный список HTML с помощью тегов <ul> и <li>?

Tags: php, html, json, ul, li

Имеется следующая Json структура.

```
{
  "menu": [
    {
      "level": "2"
    },
    {
      "level": "2"
    },
    {
      "level": "2"
    },
    {
      "level": "3"
    },
    {
      "level": "3"
    },
    {
      "level": "3"
    },
    {
      "level": "4"
    },
    {
      "level": "4"
    },
    {
      "level": "4"
    },
    {
      "level": "2"
    },
    {
      "level": "3"
    },
    {
      "level": "3"
    },
    {
      "level": "3"
    },
    {
      "level": "4"
    },
    {
      "level": "2"
    },
    {
      "level": "3"
    },
    {
      "level": "3"
    }
  ]
}
```

Как с помощью PHP трансформировать его в маркированный список HTML с помощью тегов `<ul>` и `<li>`

уточнение:

все подряд "level": "3" после "level": "2" именно его подсписок ------ все подряд "level": "4" после "level": "3" именно его подсписок и так далее

Именно этот Json будет выглядеть так

- 2
- 2
- 2

  - 3
  - 3
  - 3

    - 4
    - 4
    - 4
- 2

  - 3
  - 3
  - 3

    - 4
- 2

  - 3
  - 3

Comment: Так а в чём проблема? Где ваш пример кода? Или вы ждёте что за вас весь код для трансформации здесь напишут для копипасты?

Comment: @DanielProtopopov Если нет проблемы можете ответить. Отмечу как полагается.

Comment: @TimurVI а можете показать оригинальную json строку, которую надо преобразовать в меню??

Comment: @Alpha:  по сути она такая и есть

Comment: @TimurVI Подскажите, что-то не так?

Comment: @Denis640Kb: Все так, спасибо большое

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```php
<?php
$Json = '{
    "menu": [
    {
        "level": "2"
    },
    {
        "level": "2"
    },
    {
        "level": "2"
    },
    {
        "level": "3"
    },
    {
        "level": "3"
    },
    {
        "level": "3"
    },
    {
        "level": "4"
    },
    {
        "level": "4"
    },
    {
        "level": "4"
    },
    {
        "level": "2"
    },
    {
        "level": "3"
    },
    {
        "level": "3"
    },
    {
        "level": "3"
    },
    {
        "level": "4"
    },
    {
        "level": "2"
    },
    {
        "level": "3"
    },
    {
        "level": "3"
    }
  ]
}';

$Arr1 = json_decode($Json);
$TempArr = [];
$val = 100;
foreach ($Arr1->menu as $item){
    if($item->level < $val){
        $val = $item->level;
    }
    $TempArr[] = $item->level;
}
echo '<ul>';
for ($i=0;$i<count($TempArr);$i++){
    if (isset($TempArr[$i+1])){
        //print_r($TempArr[$i]);
        if($TempArr[$i] == $TempArr[$i+1]){
            echo '<li>' . $TempArr[$i] . '</li>';
        } elseif ($TempArr[$i] > $TempArr[$i+1]){
            $val = $TempArr[$i]-$TempArr[$i+1];
            echo '<li>'.$TempArr[$i].'</li>';
            for ($i1=0;$i1<$val;$i1++) {
                echo '</ul>';
            }
        } elseif ($TempArr[$i] < $TempArr[$i+1]){
            echo '<li>'.$TempArr[$i].'</li><ul>';
        }
    } else {
        echo '<li>'.$TempArr[$i].'</li>';
    }
}
echo '</ul>';
```

Результат:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 1):

```php
$Json = '{
    "menu": [
    {
        "level": "2"
    },
    {
        "level": "2"
    },
    {
        "level": "2"
    },
    {
        "level": "3"
    },
    {
        "level": "3"
    },
    {
        "level": "3"
    },
    {
        "level": "4"
    },
    {
        "level": "4"
    },
    {
        "level": "4"
    },
    {
        "level": "2"
    },
    {
        "level": "3"
    },
    {
        "level": "3"
    },
    {
        "level": "3"
    },
    {
        "level": "4"
    },
    {
        "level": "2"
    },
    {
        "level": "3"
    },
    {
        "level": "3"
    }
  ]
}';

$Arr1 = json_decode($Json);

echo '<ul>';
foreach ($Arr1->menu as $item){
    echo '<li>'.$item->level.'</li>';
}
echo '</ul>';
```

Comment: Спасибо за ответ. Извините если в моем вопросе видимо не точно обозначена проблема. "level": "3" это подсписок "level": "2"      ------   "level": "4" подсписок "level": "3" и так далее

Comment: @TimurVI ))) Надо чуть более конкретные вопросы задавать. КАЖДЫЙ следующий элемент является подсписком предыдущих? Или нужна сортировка по значению?

Comment: @TimurVI Таких подсписков у Вас в этом случае получится несколько. Для каждого из них нужен вложенный список, в котором так же несколько подсписков будет и так далее рекурсивно? Например в основном `ul` будет 5 вложенных `li` с `level=1`, а в каждом `level1` будет несколько подсписков с `level2` и так далее? Мне кажется это изначально не совсем корректная задача.